# Difference between sum, 'sum' and np.sum *under the hood* (Python / Pandas / Numpy)

Tags: python, pandas

How do, **sum**, **'sum'** and **np.sum** differ, under the bonnet, here:

```
df.agg(x=('A', sum), y=('B', 'sum'), z=('C', np.sum))
```

as the output would, arguably, be identical,

adapted from here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html

```
df.agg(x=('A', max), y=('B', 'min'), z=('C', np.mean))

     A    B    C
x  7.0  NaN  NaN
y  NaN  2.0  NaN
z  NaN  NaN  6.0
```

---

<sub>My guess is that the latter of the three is linked to **[Numpy](https://numpy.org/)** and the first two may be linked to **[Python](https://www.python.org/)** (and/or **[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)**), but that's just a rough, un-educated first guess... it would be interesting to know what the **single apostrophe** signifies here in this context.</sub>

Comment: unfortunately there is no `mean` function in python [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), so your code will result in a runtime error, `x=('A',mean)` is actually invalid.

Comment: No, the code actually works... EDIT: it works for `sum`... so will update the question...

Comment: What's the question? What you posted shows the results of max,min, and mean, not different `sum` calls. The only difference is speed anyway, as Pandas is built on top of Numpy which in turn uses vectorization to speed up operations like `sum`

Comment: `single apostrophe` only creates string and maybe later it convert it back to functions name using dictionary like `{"sum": numpy.sum, ...}` or `{"sum": pandas.sum, ...}`

Answer (score 1):

When you call `df.agg('sum')` it invokes `df.sum()` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73042283/3888719) for an explanation).

`df.sum` and `np.sum(df)` will have very similar performance, as pandas Series objects implement numpy's array protocols and calls to `np.sum(df)` will actually invoke something similar to `df.apply(pd.Series.sum)` under the hood. Both of these will be faster than the builtin `sum` for any meaningfully sized DataFrame, as the data is already stored as an array.

See the pandas guide to [enhancing performance](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html) for more tips.