# Python: sum column for every dataframe in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, sum

I have a list of identical dataframes and I am trying to sum one column in each dataframe in the list. My thought is something like `total = [df['A'].sum for df in dfs]` but this returns a list of length dfs containing only the value `method`. My desired output is a list of the column sum for each dataframe. What is the fastest way to achieve this goal? I have to repeat this sum thousands of times per list on thousands of different lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, you are missing `()` after `sum`

```
 total = [df['A'].sum() for df in dfs]
```

You want to call the method `sum` not just reference it.

Python `sum` is pretty quick: [Python built-in sum function vs. for loop performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578896/python-built-in-sum-function-vs-for-loop-performance) and
I assume that pandas sum should be comparable.
[Difference between sum, 'sum' and np.sum *under the hood* (Python / Pandas / Numpy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73039228/difference-between-sum-sum-and-np-sum-under-the-hood-python-pandas-num)